# Неубиваемый Service Android (Boot,Foreground,Sticky)

Tags: android, service, boot, уведомления

В основные задачи программы входит выполнение методов в фоновом режиме, для чего используется Android Services.

Необходимо запустить Service таким образом, чтобы после закрытия MainActivity сервис оставался в рабочем состоянии и мог создавать уведомления, а также, в случае закрытия системой или же перезагрузки, самостоятельно восстанавливался.

На данный момент основная проблема состоит в поддержании жизни в MyService после закрытия пользовательского интерфейса.

**AutoStart:**

В AndroidManifest.xml были прописаны

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETE"/>
```

```
<receiver android:name="ru.package.BootReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name = "android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

В BootReceiver.java:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
    context.startService(serviceIntent);
}
```

**Service:**

В AndroidManifest.xml прописано:

```
<service
        android:name="ru.package.MyService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:process=":AnyProcessName">
</service>
```

В MyService.java находится следующий код, за исключением некоторых частей (описаны наиболее важные элементы, в которых могут находиться ошибки, не позволяющие решить поставленную задачу):

```
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
    this.getSystemService(this.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
}
```

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    sendNotification("Service started", "Service", "started");
    return Service.START_STICKY;
}
```

```
public void sendNotification(String Ticker,String Title,String Text) {
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    notificationIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent)
    .setOngoing(true)   //invulnerable
    .setTicker(Ticker)
    .setContentTitle(Title)
    .setContentText(Text)
    .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());

    Notification notification;
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT<=15) {
        notification = builder.getNotification(); // API 15 and lower
    }else {
        notification = builder.build();
    }

    startForeground(DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_ID,notification);
```

```
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return new Binder();
}

@Override
public void onRebind(Intent intent) {
    super.onRebind(intent);
}

@Override
public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
    return super.onUnbind(intent);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    //Removing any notifications
    notificationManager.cancel(DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_ID);

    //Disabling service
    stopSelf();
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Запускается MyService из MainActivity следующим образом:

```
Intent intentService;
```

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    intentService = new Intent(this,MyService.class);
}
```

```
public void runService() {
    boolean working = isMyServiceRunning(MyService.class);
    if (!working) {
        startService(intentService);
    } else {
        stopService(intentService);
    }
}
```

```
public boolean isMyServiceRunning(Class<?> serviceClass) {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if (serviceClass.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Просьба указать на допущенные в ходе программирования ошибки, дополнив их сторонними материалами (примерами) или ключевыми словами для поиска.

Comment: А сервис у вас какой класс расширяет? `Service` или `IntentService`?

Comment: В данный момент:`public class MyService extends Service{`.


Необходимо произвести замену на:
`public class MyService extends IntentService {`
Добавив:
`public MyService() {
        super("anyname");
    }@Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

    }`
?

Comment: IntentService вроде  бы не должен работать постоянно. Он задачу выполняет  и завершается.

Comment: В качестве примера работы могу предложить для анализа приложение "Будильник Xtreme". Приложение автоматически запускается вместе с сервисом после загрузки смартфона, а также восстанавливается после закрытия в recentTaskBar. Всё это происходит в фоновом режиме, т.е. пользовательский интерфейс каждый раз не открывается, однако в списке уведомлений всегда держится сообщение о том, что сервис находится в рабочем состоянии. Процесс в диспетчере всего один, к которому и прикреплён Service. В случае закрытия процесса автоматически происходит Restart.

Comment: Почитав на просторах Интернета информацию по запуску сервиса после закрытия, я выяснил, что после Force stop приложения сервис не может быть повторно вызван никаким образом, однако вышеназванный будильник справляется с этой задачей.

На данный момент стоит задача наладить автозапуск сервиса после загрузки смартфона. Возможно, что для этого потребуется WakeLock.

Comment: Выяснились новые подробности: Вышеназванные функции были неработоспособными по той простой причине, что приложение устанавливалось как debug-app из интерфейса Android Studio, а не как рабочее релизное приложение вручную из проводника. На данный момент все функции приложения успешно реализованы.В ближайшее время я размещу под данным вопросом отредактированную версию кода в виде ответа.

Comment: Да, подробный ответ будет крайне интересен и полезен. Ждём)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Для адекватной работы всех предъявленных к "бессмертному" сервису требований потребовалось деинсталлировать нерабочую версию с устройства, после чего загрузить свежую сборку. Вызвано это было, вероятнее всего, именно разрешениями. Построение своей программы я начал практически с нуля, поэтому после первой установки приложению было выдано недостаточное для реализации функций "бессмертного" сервиса количество разрешений. На данный момент приложением используется всего два разрешения: Notifications и Autostart. На эту мысль меня натолкнула полная работоспособность приложения на всех прочих устройствах.

Я постараюсь отразить в этом ответе все элементы кода, необходимые для работы "бессмертного" сервиса.

**Android Manifest:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<service
    android:name=".MyService"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true" >
</service>

<receiver
    android:name=".MyReceiver"
    android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"
    android:enabled="true">

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.REBOOT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>

</receiver>
```

**MainActivity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Intent intentService;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        intentService = new Intent(this,MyService.class);
    }

    public void click_Service(View v) {
        if (!isMyServiceRunning(MyService.class)) {
            startService(intentService);
        } else {
            stopService(intentService);
        }
    }

    private boolean isMyServiceRunning(Class<?> serviceClass) {
        ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

        for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
            if (serviceClass.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

**MyService:**

```
public class MyService extends Service {
    private NotificationManager notificationManager;
    public static final int DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_ID = 101;

    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        notificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(this.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    }

    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        //Send Foreground Notification
        sendNotification("Ticker","Title","Text");

        //Task
        doTask();

        //return Service.START_STICKY;
        return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
    }

    //Send custom notification
    public void sendNotification(String Ticker,String Title,String Text) {

        //These three lines makes Notification to open main activity after clicking on it
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        notificationIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        notificationIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent)
            .setOngoing(true)   //Can't be swiped out
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            //.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.large))   // большая картинка
            .setTicker(Ticker)
            .setContentTitle(Title) //Заголовок
            .setContentText(Text) // Текст уведомления
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());

        Notification notification;
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT<=15) {
            notification = builder.getNotification(); // API-15 and lower
        }else{
            notification = builder.build();
        }

        startForeground(DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        //Removing any notifications
        notificationManager.cancel(DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_ID);

        //Disabling service
        stopSelf();
    }
}
```

**MyReceiver:**

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent intentService = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
        context.startService(intentService);
    }
}
```

Таким образом, мы получаем сервис, который автоматически запускается после старта системы. Пользовательский интерфейс может быть вызван нажатием на уведомление, которое невозможно убрать из панели уведомлений. После открытия пользовательского интерфейса сервис может быть отключён или включён вручную нажатием на соответствующую кнопку. В случае закрытия приложения, включая свайп приложения из Recent Task Bar'а, сервис останется включённым и продолжит свою работу.

Единственным возможным способом закончить работу MyService без использования пользовательского интерфейса является закрытие процесса Application при помощи Force Stop в списке приложений или же остановка самого процесса вручную в меню настроек системы.

Comment: Друг у тебя получилось?

Comment: специально зарегистрировался , чтобы сказать, что это неправильный ответ. нужно будить устройство и держать сервис в режиме awake

Comment: Более того, правильно использовать alarmmanager, а не это "типа правильно".

Comment: процесс на совмременных апаратах вообще может убиваться системой, и ничего не спасёт.

Comment: @Vyacheslav а как работает приложения звонки на телефоне, когда поступает входящий вызов?)))

Comment: @FORTRAN Давно не занимался этой темой. Но это, видимо, или системное приложение, которое будет до последнего выживать, или умрёт раньше. Не подскажу, если честно. Нужно тестировать на старых и слабых аппаратах.

Comment: @Vyacheslav т.е. вприцепе системное приложения и получаеться и являеться чатсичным решением)