# Как правильно сделать проект GUI + Service

Tags: android, android-service

Приложение состоит из ГУИ и сервиса, необходимо, что бы приложение устанавливалось вместе с сервисом, но при уничтожении ГУИ сервис продолжал работать. Если делаю все в одном проекте, то при уничтожении гуи сервис тоже прибивается. Как правильно сделать?

Comment: Используйте `Foreground Service`

Comment: еще вот вопрос о том же, что и у вас http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/481176/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B9-service-android-boot-foreground-sticky

Comment: Метки (теги) нужны для того, чтобы выделить основные моменты ВОПРОСА, по которым другие пользователи быстрее смогут найти решение аналогичной проблемы, а не для демонстрации собственных предпочтений в выборе IDE. Вопрос никак не связан с проблемами при работе IDE Android Studio и этот тег в вопросе не нужен