# Android Как обеспечить работу сервиса в экстренном режиме питания, или его перезапуск при выходе из этого режима?

Tags: android-service

Android Как обеспечить работу сервиса в экстренном режиме питания, или его перезапуск при выходе из этого режима?

есть пример неубиваемого сервиса - [Неубиваемый Service Android (Boot,Foreground,Sticky)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/481176/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B9-service-android-boot-foreground-sticky)

он хорошо работает, но когда включается экстренный режим питания сервис завершает работу, как этого избежать или обеспечить автоматический перезапуск после выхода их экстренного режима?

Comment: Экстренный режим питания - battery saver?