# Неубиваемый Service в Android

Tags: java, android, service

Нужно сделать чтобы мой Service не убивался системой и и другими чистилками мусора.

Сам код:

**Manifest.xml**

```
<service
        android:name=".NotificationService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETE"
        android:process=":BatMonitoring">
    </service>

    <receiver
        android:name=".BootReceiver"
        android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"
        android:enabled="true">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.REBOOT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>

    </receiver>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    intentService = new Intent(this,NotificationService.class);
    startService(intentService);
}
```

**BootReceiver.java**

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, NotificationService.class);
            context.startService(serviceIntent);
    }
}
```

**NotificationService.java**

```
public class NotificationService extends Service {

    private NotificationManager notificationManager;
    public static final int DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_ID = 101;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        notificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        this.registerReceiver(this.mBatteryInfoReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));


    }


    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        return START_STICKY;

    }
    BroadcastReceiver mBatteryInfoReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            int level = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
            int chargeState = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS, -1);

            int status = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS, -1);
            boolean isCharging = status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING ||
                    status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_FULL;

            switch (chargeState) {
                case BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING:

                    if (isCharging) {

                        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(NotificationService.this)
                                .setContentTitle("Charging...")
                                .setContentText("Battery level is: " + Integer.toString(level))
                                .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_notify_chat);

                        Notification notification = builder.build();
                        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
                        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

                        startForeground(DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);

                    }
                    break;

                case BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_FULL:

                    break;
                case BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_DISCHARGING:

                    break;
            }

        }
    };


   @Override
    public void onDestroy () {
        super.onDestroy();

        notificationManager.cancel(DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_ID);
        this.unregisterReceiver(this.mBatteryInfoReceiver);

        //Disabling service
        stopSelf();
    }


    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Одним из примеров брал этот [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/481176/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B9-service-android-boot-foreground-sticky) ,но все равно не работает как должно.

Буду очень благодарен любой помощи!

**UPD:** Окончательно вопрос не решил, но если кому нужно, то добавление перезапуска сервиса в void onDestroy () и в onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) частично помогло.

Comment: Рекомендую почитать [эту статью](https://habrahabr.ru/post/265159/).

Comment: Спасибо, перечитал еще раз, но ничего нового для себя или для решения данного вопроса, так и не открыл.

Comment: Как по мне, то существование неубиваемого сервиса противоречит здравому смыслу. Если бы такой сервис существовал, то телефон нельзя было бы выключить (сервис ведь при этом остановиться!). А также телефон не мог бы разрядиться.
Но допустим, что все таки создали такой сервис и он умудрился выжрать всю память. Система не может его убить (он же не убиваемый), но и продолжать выполнять не может (памяти нет).

На самом деле можно все таки сделать - если он будет частью системы - то есть, собрать свою сборку. В этом случае можно будет чуточку больше контролировать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тоже долго ищу официальный путь сделать такой сервис.

Попробовал сделать startForeground() для сервиса запущенного в отдельном процессе и это сработало. По крайней мере процесс остаётся живым и notification отображатеся. Но это для тех сервисов, которые можно отображать пользователю.

Второй вариант, когда пользователю не надо ничего отображать. Глядите цитату:

> ## Привязка к запущенной службе.
>
> Как указано в статье Службы, можно создать службу, которая
> одновременно и запущена, и привязана. Это означает, что службу можно
> запустить путем вызова метода startService(), который позволяет службе
> работать неограниченное время, а также позволяет клиентам
> привязываться к ней с помощью вызова метода bindService().
>
> Если разрешить запуск и привязку службы, то после ее запуска **система
> не уничтожает** ее после отмены всех привязок клиентов. Вместо этого
> необходимо явным образом остановить службу, вызвав метод stopSelf()
> или stopService(). Несмотря на то, что обычно необходимо реализовывать
> либо метод onBind(), либо метод onStartCommand(), в некоторых случаях
> требуется реализовать оба этих метода. Например, в музыкальном
> проигрывателе может оказаться полезным **разрешить выполнение службы в
> течение неограниченного времени**, а также обеспечить ее привязку. Таким
> образом, операция может запустить службу для воспроизведения музыки ,
> которая будет воспроизводиться даже после выхода пользователя из
> приложения. После того возвращения пользователя к приложению операция
> может отменить привязку к службе, чтобы вернуть управление
> воспроизведением.

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html#Lifecycle