# Прием сообщений о входящем вызове на android 7+

Tags: android, broadcast-receiver

Суть задачи в том, чтобы при звонке на устройство мы могли так или иначе обработать вызов в зависимости от номера звонящего. Проблема в том, что оно вообще не ловит интент, логи, прописанные в приемнике, не выводятся. Код манифеста:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="roninapps.callblocker">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_NUMBERS"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name=".CallReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Код обработчика:

```
package roninapps.callblocker;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class CallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i("Receiver", "onReceive");
        String phoneState = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
        if (phoneState.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
            Log.i("Receiver", "ringing");
            String incomingNumber = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
            Toast.makeText(context, incomingNumber, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Тестировал на эмуляторе Android 6 и Android 9.
Пытаясь разобраться, написал простенький пробник.
Манифест:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.pavlo.receiver_broadcaster_demo">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name=".BReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="NEWBR"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Приемник:

```
package com.example.pavlo.receiver_broadcaster_demo;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class BReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public BReceiver() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i("mylog", "onReceive");
        Toast.makeText(context, "received", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Активность:

```
package com.example.pavlo.receiver_broadcaster_demo;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String NEW_BR = "NEWBR";
    public static final String BRDATA = "brdata";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        Log.i("mylog", "sent");
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(NEW_BR);
        intent.putExtra("BRData", BRDATA);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES);
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
}
```

Работает только на Android 6. На 9 приема не происходит. Вопрос: а)почему даже внутреннее намерение не ловится на андроиде выше 6? б)как реализовать обработку вызова, все ли разрешения у меня прописаны, где косяк и что делать/гуглить?

//правка №1, 18.12
Поправил активность, добавив запрос разрешений. На шестом андроиде заработало. На девятом интенты все равно не ловятся.
Код активности:

```
package roninapps.callblocker;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_READ_PHONE_STATE = 1;
    private static boolean READ_PHONE_STATE_GRANTED = false;
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_READ_PHONE_NUMBERS = 2;
    private static boolean READ_PHONE_NUMBERS_GRANTED = false;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        int hasReadPhoneStatePermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE);
        int hasReadPhoneNumbersPermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_NUMBERS);

        if (hasReadPhoneStatePermission == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.i("permissions", "phone state granted");
            READ_PHONE_STATE_GRANTED = true;
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE}, REQUEST_CODE_READ_PHONE_STATE);
        }

        if (hasReadPhoneNumbersPermission == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.i("permissions", "phone number granted");
            READ_PHONE_NUMBERS_GRANTED = true;
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_NUMBERS}, REQUEST_CODE_READ_PHONE_NUMBERS);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {

        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_CODE_READ_PHONE_STATE:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    READ_PHONE_STATE_GRANTED = true;
                    Log.i("permissions", "phone state allowed");
                }
            case REQUEST_CODE_READ_PHONE_NUMBERS:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    READ_PHONE_NUMBERS_GRANTED = true;
                    Log.i("permissions", "phone numbers allowed");
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Возможно дело в ограничениях для фоновых процессов, которые вроде бы с 24 API актуальны. Они оставили небольшое количество броадкастов, которые все-таки можно слушать. Вот [здесь](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes?hl=ru#bg-opt) описание на русском, а [здесь](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions) список броадкастов, которые можно слушать.

Comment: Если так, то чем это можно заменить? Необходимо именно отслеживать входящие звонки.

Comment: Похоже, что в API 29 добавили броадкаст ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED, вот [здесь](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager#ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED) описание его и какие разрешения нужно прописать в манифесте

Comment: Попробовал добавить. На шестом все и так работало, на девятом не работает. Кстати, вроде же он у меня зарегистрирован константой  "android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"? Еще раз обращу внимание - на девятом у меня вообще ничего не ловит, включая внутренние сообщения. По моему, проблема где-то в ресивере, на уровне объявления в манифесте.

Comment: Если в активити явно зарегистрировать ресивер (запуск в onResume, остановка в onPause), то внутренние сообщения приходят [вот так](https://pastebin.com/7N2n8P4W)

Comment: Проверил: звонки тоже приходят, но только пока активити запущена.

Comment: Этот способ я знаю, но нужна именно фоновая работа. Спасибо за помощь, но пока все не то( Если коротко - приложение блокирует звонки по принципу "белого списка", т.е. нужна работа в фоне(с этим проблемы) и сверка номера со списком(импорт из контактов, здесь все хорошо). Получится разобраться с фоновой работой - считай все написал.

Comment: Наверное, это не лучшее решение, но вроде заработало([ссылка](https://gist.github.com/tinted-knight/b2e1ccf874e368f1ec51f0ef76ac39ec)): `foreground service` с постоянно присутствующей иконкой в строке состояния. При свернутой активити пишет в лог, что принимает звонки. По идее, нужно еще допилить, чтобы грузился при загрузке системы. Проверил на API 27. Код подсмотрен [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/481176/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B9-service-android-boot-foreground-sticky)

Comment: Tinted Knight, огромное спасибо. С интентами уже разобрался, сервис прикручу как будет время. Вопрос еще пару дней повисит, вдруг еще кто чего скажет, но в целом решение есть.