# Фоновое прослушивание аудио без создания нового активити

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно реализовать фоновое прослушивание, чтобы при открытии плеера в приложении у меня открывался старый активити (т.е. я мог поставить песню на паузу и увидеть значение seekbar(прогресса)).

Сейчас, если я сверну приложение, или открою другой раздел приложения и вернусь в плеер, я заново могу запустить песню, т.е. создается новое активити плеера и начинает играть одна песня одновременно два раза

**Отрывок кода, связанный с этим вопросом:**

```
  // создаем плеер и задаем источник
        mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        try {
            mPlayer.setDataSource(path);
            mPlayer.prepare();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.btnPlay: // кнопка "play/pause"
                if (!mPlayer.isPlaying())
                    btnPlay();
                else
                btnPause();
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }

    }

// кнопка "play"
    private void btnPlay() {
        if (!mPlayer.isPlaying())
            mPlayer.start();
    }

// кнопка "pause"
private void btnPause() {
if (mPlayer.isPlaying())
    mPlayer.pause();
}
```

Само фоновое прослушивание реализовал тем, что закомментил строки освобождения ресурсов, что, по-сути, не верно:

```
//освобождает используемые проигрывателем ресурсы
    private void releaseMP() {

        if (mPlayer != null) {
            try {
                mPlayer.release();
                mPlayer = null;
            } catch (Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

// освобождаем ресурсы проигрывателя при выходе из приложения
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        releaseMP();
    }
```

Comment: Вам нужно использовать Service для этого

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Смотрите, основная идея это воспроизводить аудио в другом потоке, то что вы и делаете, но вам как-то нужно после закрытия активити и последующим открытием, получать доступ к этому самому потоку, для этого можно сделать множество самых разных решений, но как по мне самым простым и правельным является:

1. [Создаём сервис, для версия апи28+ (будет запускаться foregroundService)](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services), и привязываем к нему неубиваемую нотификашку (можно реализовать что-то подобное вот [этому](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/482964/238266)), решений много и для каждой задачи своё, универсального решения нет, гуглите (это самый мощьный ваш инструмент). Такое решение делает отличный задел на будущее: вы в этой нотификашке можете сделать доступ к плееру: плей, пауза и т.д.
2. В этом сервисе создаете новый поток и удерживаете на него ссылку, пока проигрование не будет остановлено (важно, останавливаете и создавайте новый поток токо если воспроизведение было остановлено (хотя и это в некоторых ситуциях не факт что спасёт ваш сервис от уничтожения системой на разных печальных устройствах)).
3. В сервисе реализовываем все функции управления ваши плеером(лучше это сделать через интерфейсы, но если опыта мало делаете обычно, с опытом понимаение прийдёт).
4. Всё, осталось сделать только управление из активити, где вы при открытии активити связываетесь с вашим сервисом, если его нет создаём, иначе подвязываемся и управляем вашим плеером.

P.S. Вы можете уже что-то опенсёрсное и делать либо на нём либо брать оттуда решения, так я делал с будильником. Вот неплохой [ресурс](https://androiddev.apptractor.ru/38-luchshih-open-source-android-proektov-na-java/). Мне нравится вот это решение под названием [Shuttle](https://github.com/timusus/Shuttle). 1m+ скачаваний.

Comment: Спасибо! Посмотрю