# Почему пропадает звук в меню Fragment? MediaPlayer

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, mediaplayer

Я не так давно изучаю android разработку и вот когда я делал приложение для воспроизведения звуков (животных) с помощью MediaPlayer, сделал даже меню с  TabLayout который содержит 5 Fragment, наткнулся на одну проблему. **Когда нажимаю на кнопки в Fragment1 звуки воспроизводятся, потом нажимаю на все остальные кнопки в других фрагментах некоторые звуки воспроизводятся, а некоторые нет. Вот смотрите, к примеру, Нажал на все кнопки в Fragment5, потом нажал на кнопки в Fragment4, а вот когда уже дохожу до Fragment2-Fragment1, то звуки не воспроизводятся.**
 Код конечно не очень красив, т.к. не особо шарю в "дизайне кода" хдд. **Буду рад всем ответам)**

**MainActivity**

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
     * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
     * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
     * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
     * may be best to switch to a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */
    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    private ViewPager mViewPager;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);


        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(200);

        mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(mViewPager));

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main2, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }


    }

    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
           // return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
            switch (position){

                case 0:
                    return  new BlankFragment();

                case 1:
                    return  new BlankFragment2();

                case 2:
                    return new BlankFragment3();

                case 3:
                    return  new BlankFragment4();

                case 4:
                    return new BlankFragment5();

                default:
                    return null;
            }

        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return 5;
        }
    }
}
```

**Один из Fragments**

Все фрагменты скидывать не вижу смысла т.к. код там почти одинаковый

```
public class BlankFragment4 extends Fragment {


    MediaPlayer sound, sound1, sound2, sound3, sound4;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank_fragment4, container, false);


        ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.imageButton);

        sound = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.delfiiin);
        imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (sound1 != null) {
                    sound1.stop();
                }
                if (sound2 != null) {
                    sound2.stop();
                }
                if (sound3 != null) {
                    sound3.stop();
                }
                if (sound4 != null) {
                    sound4.stop();
                }
                sound.release();
                sound = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.delfiiin);
                sound.start();


            }
        });

        ImageButton imageButton2 = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);

        sound1 = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.kasatkaa);
        imageButton2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (sound != null) {
                    sound.stop();
                }
                if (sound2 != null) {
                    sound2.stop();
                }
                if (sound3 != null) {
                    sound3.stop();
                }
                if (sound4 != null) {
                    sound4.stop();
                }

                sound1.release();
                sound1 = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.kasatkaa);
                sound1.start();


            }
        });

        ImageButton imageButton3 = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.imageButton3);

        sound2 = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.kittt);
        imageButton3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (sound != null) {
                    sound.stop();
                }
                if (sound1 != null) {
                    sound1.stop();
                }
                if (sound3 != null) {
                    sound3.stop();
                }
                if (sound4 != null) {
                    sound4.stop();
                }
                sound2.release();
                sound2 = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.kittt);
                sound2.start();


            }
        });

        ImageButton imageButton4 = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.imageButton4);

        sound3 = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.morskoikot);
        imageButton4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (sound != null) {
                    sound.stop();
                }
                if (sound1 != null) {
                    sound1.stop();
                }
                if (sound2 != null) {
                    sound2.stop();
                }
                if (sound4 != null) {
                    sound4.stop();
                }
                sound3.release();
                sound3 = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.morskoikot);
                sound3.start();


            }
        });

        ImageButton imageButton5 = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.imageButton5);

        sound4 = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.tulenn);
        imageButton5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (sound != null) {
                    sound.stop();
                }
                if (sound1 != null) {
                    sound1.stop();
                }
                if (sound3 != null) {
                    sound3.stop();
                }
                if (sound2 != null) {
                    sound2.stop();
                }
                sound4.release();
                sound4 = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.tulenn);
                sound4.start();


            }
        });




        return  view;
    }

    public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не понятно что именно вы хотите сделать, но если вам не нужно всё воспроизводить одновременно то лучше  `MediaPlayer sound;` вынести в активити, а ещё лучше в сервис гляньте мой ответ [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1058931/238266). Если нужно всё воспроизводить одновременно (по несколько разных) на подобие как в играх и т.п., то вам лучше использовать [SoundPool](https://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/239-urok-127-media-soundpool.html). К вашей теме, вообще по логике работы вашего приложения, `MediaPlayer` должен крешится с `OutOfMemory` или не должны получить доступ после первого фрагмента, причём даже в другом приложении (плохой опыт пользователя), вы должны вызывать `release()` при окончании использования `MediaPlayer` о чём указано [тут](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#release()).

Comment: Я хочу чтобы постоянно воспроизводились звуки и не пропадали)

Comment: В смсле постоянно? В смылсе звукИ? Да же когда свёрнуто приложение хотите воспроизводить несколько разных звуков??

Comment: Окей, смотрите. Моё приложение это обычный soundboard. Просто когда я нажимаю на кнопку с Тигром например воспроизводиться звук тигра, но у меня через некоторое время эти звуки животных перестают работать при нажатии. Вот)

Comment: курите SoundPool, он вам здесь идеально подходит. Немного изначально будет сложнее, но в итоге проще получится. Если же вам нужно при нажатии прерывать уже воспроизводимый, или долждыться его завершения то можно и MediaPlayer, смотрите первую ссылку  и делайте также или в активити. Есть плохой способ, оставляйте что у вас есть, только добавьте очистку всех MediaPlayer (ваших sound*) в методе onPause() - в каждом фрагменте. Но это очень плохая практика и кроме как порадоваться что вы это писали не зря. P.S. это плохо не потому что кто-то так считает, а по тому, что этим не возможно управлять.

Comment: Немного поэкспериментировал с SoundPool(просто добавил по одной кнопке в разных Fragment и начал на них нажимать хдд ), я понял, что SoundPool намного лучше подходит к моему приложению. Короче... теперь нет такого бага с пропажей звука. Помечу ваш ответ принятым т.к. он натолкнул меня на правильную сторону. Спасибо вам огромное, я столько мучался с этим багом, а тут оказалось все так просто... еще раз спасибо!